# Is there any technical difference between a bridge and a server that subscribes to all messages on two brokers and publishes them to the other?

Tags: mqtt

This is for MQTT. I am just curious if there is any technical difference between the two or if they operate on another protocol.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionally very little, but a bridge normally has some basic protection against topic loops (Where the same message just gets bounced back and forth between the 2 brokers)

Also bridge doesn't have to bridge all topics, it can be set up to just bridge a subset of topics and can also be set to add a topic prefix bridged messages helping to distinguish between them.

Using a bridge also removes a moving part from the equation so there is less to break.

The only reason I'd even consider using a 2 back to back clients to bridge data would be if the 2 brokers where on separate networks with no route between them, and the (none routing) client connected to both networks.

Comment: @hardlib, in my situation, I have 2 brokers on separate networks and they are different applications. One is AWS IoT and the other is EMQTT, and because there is no way to bridge them built in I have built what I proposed. Do you think there is a better way of doing that?